# Vanilla Javascript click and close nav

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am still learning to do plain old vanilla javascript. I am trying to hide my slideToggle or even the whole background of the drop down menu I did to close when user clicks on the any link. Am I missing something because I am not getting any error but it doesn't display none on the slideToggle class.

js

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
     anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
var btn = document.querySelector(".slideToggle");
    if (window.getComputedStyle(btn,null).getPropertyValue("display") != 'none') {
  btn.click();
    }
  })
}
```

html

```
<nav id="mainNav">
    <h1 class="hidden">Main Navigation</h1>
        <button id="button"><span class="hidden">Toggle</span></button>
    <ul id="burgerMenu">
        <li><a href="#mainNav">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#latestWork">Latest Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#rates1">Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pageFooter">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I don't see "a" `class` in your html code.

Comment: ahhh can i not do .a href?

Comment: no.. just use "a" but it will use all `<a>` in your html.. better to add class.

Comment: dot(.) is a class selector, just use `("a")` instead of `(".a")`, there are much more errors in your code though.

Comment: the `querySelectorAll(".a")` returns all elements with the `class="a"` property

Comment: Is `.slideToggle` `button#button`?

Comment: even your `(".slideToggle")` is missing..

Comment: yep it was #button.....

Comment: Relevant links:
[MDN document.querySelectory](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

[MDN document.querySelectoryAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using document.querySelectorAll(".a") use document.querySelectorAll("a"). also I don't see an element with slideToggle as a class. using a "." as a selector means you are searching for a class.